# My code isn't writing to the text file but I'm not getting any errors

Tags: python, text-files

I am a beginner with python and I have started to develop a simple program that will scrape the current bitcoin price from a website every 5 minutes, detect the change from the previous scrape, print this information and also write it into a text file. My current code does all of this, except it fails to write it into the text document, I have no clue why.

I'm pretty sure the error is in the write() function, because that's where the error message points to, but I can include the full code if anyone thinks that that is the issue.

```
def write():
    global change
    nps = str(newPrice) + ' USD'
    writeThis = nps + ' ' + writeChange
    f.write(writeThis) 
    f.write('\n')
    print(writeThis)

with open("bitcoinPrice.txt","w+") as f:
        while True:
            getCost()
            calcChange()
            write()
```

As I'm very new to python, I understand that there are probably much better approaches to a lot of my code, and I'm completely open to suggestions!

Comment: Are `newprice` and `writeChange` defined further up in the file? Is `writeChange` supposed to be `change` here since that's the variable you're pulling in with `global change`?

Comment: your `while True` loop: although it calls your write function, it needs to close the file in order to write the buffer. Maybe you make the `while True` into a for loop that runs, say, 10 times?

Comment: Using a context manager (`with open...`) will close the file automatically when the `with` statement is exited..

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding global variables (`change`, `writeChange`, `newPrice`), for your sanity and for the sanity of others

Comment: @bug_spray I understand that global variables generally shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary, but I don't know any other ways that work...

Comment: @Harlan you can pass variables into functions when you define them, thereby giving them local scope `def some_function(variable1, variable2, *etc):`. When a function is finished, you can pass variables back using `return some_result`.

Comment: So you could do something like `change = calcChange(info)` followed by `write(f, change, newPrice)`

Comment: @Andrew I agree that the context manager will write the file when done. My `while True` comment was simply because it will never exit and the context manager will never write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the file object `f` to `write()`:

```py
def write(f):  # <-- file object
    global change
    nps = str(newPrice) + ' USD'
    writeThis = nps + ' ' + writeChange
    f.write(writeThis)
    f.write('\n')
    print(writeThis)

with open("bitcoinPrice.txt","w+") as f:
        while True:
            getCost()
            calcChange()
            write(f)  # <-- write needs to know what to write to
```